Hanging a fan from this box that I'm unfamiliar with
I'm installing a ceiling fan into what has been confirmed by my electrician to be a fan-rated box. Before I got here, there was a blank plate installed over the box, of a type I was unfamiliar with, that had no screws, and was press-fit into this bracket installed on the box (with two ~1" grabber screws):

I am not familiar with this type of box (not that I'm very familiar with many types of boxes, exactly), so I'm wondering how I'm supposed to mount the fan. The two grabber screws simply go into "slots" in the box:

I imagine that this box fits over the ceiling joist, and that screws that I drive into the "slots" are simply going into the joist, providing a solid mount. Am I correct about this? Can I simply drive the screws for the fan into those slots (and thus into the joist)?
As an aside, the fans I bought came with wood screws that were quite long (a couple inches, maybe 2.5"). Do I really need something that long, when my screws would (presumably) be going directly into the joists here?

It depends on how far the joist/wood is from the surface.  You usually want a minimum of 1.5 inches into the wood itself(more is nicer for hanging moving stuff).  Those black screws look like drywall screws and should not be used for a fan.

What you have is a "saddle box".  It does mount as a saddle over a joist or the bottom chord of a truss.
Yes you need long screws to securely mount a fan into the wood.  2 1/2 inch would be minimum. After the thickness of the box and the fan mount only about 1 3/4 inches would be into wood.
Remove the 2 black screws that are in the slots and use the longer screws.  Leave the other screws. They secure the box to the joist.

That does appear to be a fan rated junction box. If I were you, I'd remove it from the ceiling to make sure it's mounted correctly to the joist. Better yet, get a new one at your home store. It will come with the proper screws to secure it to the joist since the ones there now appear to be drywall screws and will not secure the box or fan correctly. Follow the instructions that will be provided with the junction box and the fan.
